# AsteriskNow cannot find ari.conf

Tags: rest, asterisk

I just installed AsteriskNow-6.12.65.14 and I want to try REST API. I've read a lot of tutorials, but I can't find `ari.conf` in the `/etc/asterisk/` folder.

This is my first experience configuring Asterisk so I might just be missing something fundamental.

---

Asterisk 12
AsteriskNow-6.12.65.14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as  i know asterisknow not offer experemental features like ARI.

You have create config files yourself if you need it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It means that I simply need to create ari.conf and this is the only step that I need to do?

Comment: You also need ensure you have modules in asterisk and correct asterisk version with rest api support(12.0+)

Comment: Acordinly to this page it can have 11 or 12 version http://wiki.freepbx.org/display/FD/FreePBX-Distro-6.12.65

Comment: Sorry, but where can I download those modules? I`ve seen asterisk.org and there is no info about modules. By the way, I`ve used "asterisk-version-switch" and changed asterisk version to 12 ;)

Comment: Okay, thank you. Im gonna try to build everything from scratch

Comment: No idea. Check in /usr/lib/asterisk/modules/ what you have. Check via yum search asterisk12 what you have in repo.